# Why do i need to create object of `QApplication` and what is the purpose of it in PyQt GUI programming?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

```
def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    w.show()

    app.exec()
```

This is a very simple Python GUI program with `PyQt5` framework. Actually I'm not familiar with Qt, also a newbie to GUI programming. As in above program, there is a object of `QApplication` has created as well as QWidget. In this case, `app` object doesn't contain the `w` object and i don't see any connection between two of them. So why it's necessary to create a object of `QApplication` and to execute it using that object?
Thank you!

Comment: Please read ANY introduction to Qt. There it should be explained why you need a QApplication, or which options you have if your application does not need a UI. [Here is a introduction that covers that.](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Beginners)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't *need* to create QApplication, but it's a convenience class that does a lot of things for you.

I won't explain everything it can possibly do for you -- you'll find that in [the manual](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html) -- but I can explain two of the things you're doing in your sample code.

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
```

Here you're creating the QApplication, and passing in arguments to its constructor. Qt [understands certain arguments](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#QApplication) that can be used when executing the application.

```
app.exec_()
```

Like you said, there doesn't appear to be any interaction between `app` and `w`. But there is a connection!

In order for Qt's GUI to function it needs an event loop in the main thread. The call to `exec_()` starts this event loop.

To quote the documentation for [QApplication::exec()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#exec):

> Enters the main event loop and waits until exit() is called, then
>   returns the value that was set to exit() (which is 0 if exit() is
>   called via quit()).
>
> It is necessary to call this function to start event handling. The
>   main event loop receives events from the window system and dispatches
>   these to the application widgets.

So as soon as you call `exec_()`, control leaves your `main()` function and starts responding to UI events until you tell it to exit.

Pretty much all desktop GUIs work this way to some extent, though not all of them have a nice Application object that sets up the event loop for you.  If you're new to event driven programming you might want to read up on the concepts. [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) isn't a bad place to start.

Comment: Actually, it is a requirement to have a `QApplication` object before you try and create any `QWidget` object, whether you use the event queue or not. `QApplication` is not just a convenience class, it basically sets up most of the core behind-the-scenes GUI objects that are necessary for any GUI system to run. This is in addition to all the core Qt functionality that `QtCoreApplication` sets up and controls.